# Odds Ratio, More Likely vs. As Likely, do I need to subtract 1?

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio, reporting

When reporting odds ratios from a logistic regression, I've seen the words "as likely" and "more likely." If the odds ratio is say 3.5, I know that I can say females are 3.5 times as likely as males to graduate high school, however, this "as likely" doesn't make much sense to the general public. Can I simply say females are 3.5 times "more likely" to graduate males, or do I need to subtract 1 from the 3.5, and say female students are 2.5 times more likely to graduate than males?

Comment: Where does the notion to subtract 1 from the odds ratio come from?

Comment: The idea that you should normally use the words "as likely," but that the word "more," means that that you would mathematically need to subtract 1 to justify using the word "more likely." This is according to a colleague. I've never heard of this rational, and so I thought I would check in with the broader stats community.